# If $u_n \to u$ in $H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$, does $f(u_n) \to f(u)$ in $H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$ for $f$ Lipschitz?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with $|f'(x)| \leq C$ for all $x$ and $f(0)=0$.

Suppose $u_n \to u$ in $H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain of class $C^2$. Here, I use the norm
$$|u|_{H^{\frac 12}(\partial \Omega)}^2 = |u|^2_{L^2(\partial\Omega)} + \int_{\partial\Omega}\int_{\partial\Omega} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^n}.$$

Does it follow that $f(u_n) \to f(u)$ in $H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$ (at least for a subsequence)?

---

Note that $f(u) \in H^{\frac 12}$ by the Lipschitz nature of $f$. The only issue is in the convergence of the seminorm, which I can't seem to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**
It might be more convenient to think of $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ as a quotient space:
$$
H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)=H^1(\Omega)/H^1_0(\Omega).
$$
Let $T:H^1(\Omega)\to H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ be the corresponding quotient map (the trace map).
Since $u_n\to u$ in $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, there is are functions $v_n,v\in H^1(\Omega)$ so that $v_n\to v$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ and $T(v_n)=u_n$ and $T(v)=u$.
The trace map and composing with $f$ commute with each other and $T$ is continuous, so it suffices to show that $f\circ v_n\to f\circ v$ in $H^1(\Omega)$.
It follows from theorems 1 and 5 in [this paper](http://users.minet.uni-jena.de/~sickel/japan%28v4%29.pdf) that $H^1(\Omega)\ni w\mapsto f\circ w\in H^1(\Omega)$ is continuous, from which the convergence follows.
It suffices that $f$ is Lipschitz; smoothness is not required.

Comment: Thank you. I just found a direct argument to show continuity: Lemma 2.5 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.6017.pdf. But yours is a nice technique.